# WinForms DataGridView does not respond while listing images

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have an application that allows the users to upload the selected images to the DataGridView and perform  operations on their. However, when multiple images are selected, the Form freezes until the image information is uploaded to the DataGridView. I have tried BackgroundWorker for this, but it didn't work either. My codes look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        Filter = @"TIFF |*.tiff| TIF|*.tif",
        FilterIndex = 1,
        Title = @"Select TIFF file(s)...",
        Multiselect = true
    };
    if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Listing(file.FileNames);
    }
}
private void Listing(string[] files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var pic_name = Path.GetFileName(file);

        if (file != null)
        {
            // Image from file
            var img = Image.FromFile(file);
            // Get sizes of TIFF image
            var pic_sizes = img.Width + " x " + img.Height;
            // Get size of TIFF image
            var pic_size = new FileInfo(file).Length;
            //Create the new row first and get the index of the new row
            var rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            //Obtain a reference to the newly created DataGridViewRow 
            var row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
            //Now this won't fail since the row and columns exist 
            row.Cells["name"].Value = pic_name;
            row.Cells["sizes"].Value = pic_sizes + " pixels";
            row.Cells["size"].Value = pic_size + " bytes";
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT:** After Alex's comment, I tried like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        Filter = @"TIFF |*.tiff| TIF|*.tif",
        FilterIndex = 1,
        Title = @"Select TIFF file(s)...",
        Multiselect = true
    };
    if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        _ = Test(file.FileNames);
    }
}
private async Task Test(string[] s)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Listing(s));
}
private void Listing(string[] files)
{
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var pic_name = Path.GetFileName(file);

            if (file != null)
            {
                // Image from file
                var img = Image.FromFile(file);
                // Get sizes of TIFF image
                var pic_sizes = img.Width + " x " + img.Height;
                // Get size of TIFF image
                var pic_size = new FileInfo(file).Length;
                //Create the new row first and get the index of the new row
                var rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                //Obtain a reference to the newly created DataGridViewRow 
                var row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
                //Now this won't fail since the row and columns exist 
                row.Cells["name"].Value = pic_name;
                row.Cells["sizes"].Value = pic_sizes + " pixels";
                row.Cells["size"].Value = pic_size + " bytes";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But unfortunately the result is same.

Comment: A simple solution would be to change `Listing(file.FileNames);` to `await Task.Run(() => Listing(file.FileNames));` and adding `private async void` in a signature of the first function. But it won't work, since you can't update your datagridview from another thread (in fact, you can manipulate with Windows Forms only from the main thread). So ideally you need to rewrite everything: load images in the background worker in a `List<Image>` (without modifying datagridview), and after its completion (using such event of background worker), you generate new rows and add them in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the whole problem is in collecting image datas. Because a ready list will not take longer to load if it will not need extra processing. For this reason, I prepared a scenario like below.

```
private readonly BindingList<Tiff> _tiffs = new BindingList<Tiff>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Listing();
}
private void Listing()
{
    foreach (var f in _tiffs)
    {
        if (f != null)
        {
            var rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            //Obtain a reference to the newly created DataGridViewRow 
            var row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
            //Now this won't fail since the row and columns exist 
            row.Cells["ColName"].Value = f.ColName;
            row.Cells["ColSizes"].Value = f.ColSizes + " pixels";
            row.Cells["ColSize"].Value = f.ColSize + " bytes";
        }
    }
}
public static List<string> Files(string dir, string ext = "*.tiff")
{
    var DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
    return DirInfo.EnumerateFiles(ext, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(x => x.FullName).ToList();
}
public void SetSource()
{
    // Source folder of images...
    var files = Files(@"___SOURCE_DIR___");
    var total = files.Count;
    var i = 1;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var pic_name = Path.GetFileName(file);
        var img = Image.FromFile(file);
        // Get sizes of TIFF image
        var pic_sizes = img.Width + " x " + img.Height;
        // Get size of TIFF image
        var pic_size = new FileInfo(file).Length.ToString();
        _tiffs.Add(new Tiff(pic_name, pic_sizes, pic_size));
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            label1.Text = $@"{i} of {total} is added to the BindingList.";
        });
        i++;
    }
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    SetSource();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set something if you want.
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set something if you want.
}
public class Tiff
{
    public Tiff(string name, string sizes, string size)
    {
        ColName = name;
        ColSizes = sizes;
        ColSize = size;
    }
    public string ColName { get; set; }
    public string ColSizes { get; set; }
    public string ColSize { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the result:
[image]